# 'global' file or directory not found for yarn

Tags: linux, ubuntu, yarnpkg

When I try to use any command using yarn global, like '`yarn global add yo`', I get an error saying `ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'global'.`

Could not find matching solutions on the internet. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A (alternative) solution:**

When I installed yarn using [Debian package repository](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable), I got the error mentioned in the question while doing `yarn global`.

However, when I installed yarn using npm, like this:

> npm install -g yarn

I did not get the error anymore upon doing `yarn global`. Any explanation or detailed answer addressing the issue with installation using Debian package repository is welcome.

Comment: This worked! But I had to uninstall the previous "yarn" to make it work
`sudo apt remove cmdtest`

Answer (score 0):

Default `yarn` package is just an alias to `cmdtest`. It is not `yarn`.

You should remove that package and install the proper `yarn` package.

```bash
sudo apt remove cmdtest

curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install yarn
yarn --version
```